# Who was the man in Wanda's flat?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, ida

In the beginning of "Ida" (2013 [Best Foreign Language Film of the Year](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2718492/?ref_=nv_sr_2)), Anna/Ida visits her aunt Wanda for the first time.  As she enters Wanda's flat, the camera pauses on a man getting dressed.  He laters says 'God bless' to her from off screen as he leaves. In a film where every scene is dripping with nuance and plot, this one seems unresolved. Who is that guy?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man in this scene is just a random person. His presence there is to give the viewers the first impression of what type of person aunt Wanda is or will turn out to be (as this is the first time Ida meets her). And this first impression is very suggestive of someone engaging in casual sex, therefore perhaps viewers are led to think of her in not so positive terms. As the viewers get to know Wanda throughout the rest of the movie, her liking of carnal pleasures and alcohol turns out to be a way she copes with the reality around her.